# Aspnetboilerplate - AngularJS not reaching the AppService?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, angular, model-view-controller, asp.net-boilerplate

I downloaded the ASP.NET MVC with AngularJS and Entity Framework, module zero sample. I added an entity called DivePlan, with only one string property name for now.

[image]

```
namespace PlanMyDive.DivePlan
{
    public class DivePlan : Entity
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }


        public DivePlan() { }
        public DivePlan(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }

    }
}
```

Then I created a service in the application layer:

[image]

```
namespace PlanMyDive.DivePlan.Dto
{
    [AutoMapTo(typeof(DivePlan))]
    public class CreateDivePlanInput
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
}

namespace PlanMyDive.DivePlan
{
    public class DivePlanAppService : IDivePlanAppService
    {
        private readonly IRepository<DivePlan> _divePlanRepository;

        public DivePlanAppService(IRepository<DivePlan> personRepository)
        {
            _divePlanRepository = personRepository;
        }

        public void CreateDivePlan(CreateDivePlanInput input)
        {
            var diveplan = input.MapTo<DivePlan>();
            _divePlanRepository.Insert(diveplan);
        }
    }
}

namespace PlanMyDive.DivePlan
{
    public interface IDivePlanAppService : IApplicationService
    {
        void CreateDivePlan(CreateDivePlanInput input);
    }
}
```

Finally, I added a page Plans in the Angular routes and implemented as follows:

[image]

```
(function () {
    angular.module('app').controller('app.views.plans.plan', [
        '$scope', '$modal', 'abp.services.app.divePlan',
        function ($scope, $modal, divePlanService) {
            var vm = this;

            vm.divePlan = {
                name: 'MyDivePlan'
            };


            vm.createNewDivePlan = function () {
                abp.ui.setBusy();
                divePlanService.createDivePlan(vm.divePlan);
                abp.ui.clearBusy();
            };
        }
    ]);
})();

@using PlanMyDive.DivePlan
<div ng-controller="app.views.plans.plan as vm">
    <h1>Welcome to your DivePlan</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form name="planCreateForm" role="form" novalidate class="form-validation">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.createNewDivePlan()">Create Plan</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>DivePlan Name</th>
                    <th>Autre</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="plan in vm.plans">
                    <td>{{plan.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{plan.name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have a breakpoint in my JS code at the line divePlanService.createDivePlan(vm.divePlan); and a breakpoint in my DivePlanAppService when the function public void CreateDivePlan(CreateDivePlanInput input) is called. The issue I get is that the JS code executes but the DivePlanAppService function CreateDivePlan never executes, or at leave it never breaks at my breakpoint. The user interface shows the following:
[image]

I tried to simplify the code as much as I could. That's why the Service method doesn't do much so far. I noticed the constructor of DivePlanAppService is never called whereas the constructor of UserAppService is called whenever I navigate to the /#/users page.

What did I miss? Am I not providing the CreateDivePlanInput in the proper format? I tried to copy how TenantAppService works. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I went to dig and debug in the CastleDynamicInterceptor and found this error message regarding my DivePlanAppService:

> Some dependencies of this component could not be statically resolved.
>   'PlanMyDive.DivePlan.DivePlanAppService' is waiting for the following dependencies:
>   - Service 'Abp.Domain.Repositories.IRepository`1[[PlanMyDive.DivePlan.DivePlan, PlanMyDive.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' which was not registered.

Answer (score 1):

I think **DivePlan**  entity not registered on **dbcontext**.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **DivePlan** to **DbContext**

```
public class PlanMyDiveDbContext : AbpDbContext
{
    //other entities       
    public virtual IDbSet<DivePlan> DivePlans { get; set; }

    ...
}
```